# Enter on Mondays only

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to enter trades on mondays only on the daily timeframe, so i have plotted friday as the trigger. But sometimes like Christmas there is no friday and the week finishes on thursday. How can i get my strategy to still enter on monday if there is no friday?

Symbol - OANDA:SPX500USD

Thank you

````
strategy("enter on mondays", overlay=true)

// chart - OANDA:SPX500USD

i_sessionTime       = input.session("1700-1700", title="session")
sessionString       = i_sessionTime

f_sessionFilter     = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionString, syminfo.timezone))

// friday
friday = dayofweek==dayofweek.thursday

if friday
    strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long)

if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.close(id="Long", comment="Exit")

plotshape(friday)```
````

Comment: How about you use `process_orders_on_close` and check if it is a monday instead?

Comment: Thanks, have tried that but still can't get it to work. Basically i just want it to enter on mondays open and close on mondays close. But sometimes in the year there is no friday, the week ends on thursday so need to navigate for that too.

Comment: This is where Pine falls short, your script is inherently attached to the timeframe you are watching and that controls the execution of your code (at the end, or on every tick, but you cannot backtest the tick version). If you don't mind your backtest being shorter than on the daily chart, attach your script to a lower timeframe (say, 5 minutes) and handle day's end yourself. Then you can enter the trade 5 minutes after Monday's opening.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

we save the "dayofweek" value of every day, and as soon a new day starts, we check if the last day we saved was a "Thursday" and today is a "Monday".

```
var lastday = 0
var noFriday = false

if dayofweek != lastday

    //this "if" will only be true if lastday was thursday and today is a monday
    if lastday == dayofweek.thursday and dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        noFriday := true

    //this keeps updating the lastday variable every new day
    lastday := dayofweek
```

you can then write some logic that checks the prior day for a signal, either by using something like "close[1]" if it's on a daily timeframe, or by writing a for loop that goes over the prior day's bars to check for the signal.

if you need to do a for loop, you can save the bar_index of the first bar of the day when updating lastday to dayweek in the last line in the code above, then you can use this index for the loop.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i'm using Daily timeframe. Have tried to write code to check prior day but not got it yet.